# why doesn't the highlighted section of code work and what do i need to change to make it able to work

Tags: python-3.x

I just deleted my previous question as someone made it embarrassingly obvious that I didn't ask an actual question with a main goal.I apologise for this. 
I am only referring to the last part of the code. The "A" option as i cannot figure out why it is incorrect

The full thing works other than the A section it says there is a syntax error. That's it. 
I've tried re placing the brackets and playing around with them and so on.

```
def Jobs():
    def Parse_Line(Job_Line):
        Job_Line = Job_Line.strip()
        Estimate_Number, Estimate_Date, Customer_ID, Final_Total, Job_Status,Amount_Pay= Job_Line.split(",") 
        Painting_Job = {
            'Estimate_Number':Estimate_Number,
            'Estimate_Date':Estimate_Date,
            'Customer_ID':Customer_ID,
            'Final_Total':Final_Total,
            'Job_Status':Job_Status,
            'Amount_Pay':Amount_Pay,
            }
        return Painting_Job

        Job_List = []
        with open("paintingJobs.txt", "r") as Painting_Jobs:
                for line in Painting_Jobs:
                    Job_List.append(Parse_Line(line))
        return Job_List

def Accepted(job):
    return job['Job_Status'] == "A"


def Outstanding(job):
        return int(job['Final_Total']) - int(job['Amount_Pay'])

Job_List = Jobs()

print ("\nOption A: Search for an estimate\n\nOption B: Dislay the outstanding payments\n\nOption C: Display your total revenue\n\nOr Press Q to quit")

Option_Choice = input("Which option do you want to do?")

if Option_Choice == "A" or Option_Choice == "a":
            Estimate_no = input("Please enter the required estimate number so we search our database: ")
            Estimate_Found = Estimate_no
            job in Job_List if ['Estimate_Number'] == Estimate_no
            if Estimate_Found:
                    print (Estimate_Found)
```

Comment: You should probably describe how it does not work/how it fails as well.

Comment: What's the error? Is there a traceback? Unexpected output?

Comment: jDo it's a syntax error which is annoying

Comment: ...what is the syntax error? We are not going to run the code you gave us, you need to describe what the error is.

Comment: I'm not sure the python code just says "syntax error"